# Can I access an outer class's field from a static inner class?

Tags: java

I have a class which has another `static` inner class:

```
class A {
    private List<String> list;

    public static class B {
        // I want to update list here without making list as static 
        // I don't have an object for outer class
    }
}
```

Comment: A static nested class does not have an implicit reference to any instance of the surrounding class. You would need to pass it a reference to the instance you want it to modify. Why is class B static?

Comment: Class B was generating just a template structure for UI display, now i am performing some operation to get the value and that needs to set to surrounding class . is this a design issue?

Comment: If you need each B instance to relate to a specific A instance, and be able to operate on it, the simplest solution would be to make B non-static, and establish that relationship at construction time.

Comment: I can reformulate the comment as "I don't have an A, but I want to change its list." Does that make it more obvious that your question doesn't make sense?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you can see from other answers that you will need a non-static inner class to do that.

If you really cannot make your inner class non-static then you can add required getter and setter method in outer class and access them by creating an instance of outer class from inside inner static class:

```
public class A {
    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<String> getList() {
        return list;
    }
    public void setList(List<String> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
    public static class B {
        // i want to update list here without making list as static
        void updList() {
            A a = new A();
            a.setList(someOtherList);
            System.out.println(a.getList());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this really a solution considering object of the class A in expression `A a = new A();` is just local, with its initial values? Can you elaborate, please?

Comment: Adding getter and setter has no relevance here, just accessing the field via `a.list` would do the same. The key point is that you create a new instance of `A`. But as [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17700602/can-i-access-an-outer-classs-field-from-a-static-inner-class#comment66802412_17701360) already said, using a temporary instance of `A` has no persistent effect.

Comment: Since it is a static inner class (and `list` is non-static), we need an explicit instance to access it otherwise we could simply use `A.this.list`

Answer (score 17):

You generally use static classes when you **don't** need access to the instance variables. If you need to access the instance variables make the class non-static.

Answer (score 6):

No, you'll need a non-`static` inner class to do that.

From the [JLS §8.5.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.5.1):

> The `static` keyword may modify the declaration of a member type `C` within the body of a non-inner class or interface `T`. Its effect is to declare that `C` is not an inner class. Just as a static method of `T` has no current instance of T in its body, `C` also has no current instance of `T`, nor does it have any lexically enclosing instances.
>
> **It is a compile-time error if a `static` class contains a usage of a non-static member of an enclosing class.**

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `list` is an instance variable of class `A` and `B` is nested static class. The rules of accessing static and not static member don't change for nested static class.

- The variable `list` is instance variable so a can't be accessed from static context.
- To enable this, you need to change static nester class to inner class.

  ```
  class A {
  private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    public class B {
       public void someMethod(){
           list.add("abc");
       }
    }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

`private List<String> list;`

Here ***list*** is an instance variable while the inner class is static which means that ***class B*** is the same across different ***class A*** instances; one cannot access it. And, that too for a very good and obvious reason.

One solution that you can use is pass reference of member ***list*** to the constructor of ***class B*** with a ***weakReference*** to avoid memory leak.

Something like this:

```
class A {
    private List<String> list;

    public static class B {
        WeakReference<List<String>> innerList;
        //constructor
        B(WeakReference<List<String>> innerList){
            this.innerList = innerList;
        }
    }
```