# Java Design Pattern Apply

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am developing one API, with following snaps of code.

**RowMappable.java**

```
package com.api.mapper;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
public interface RowMappable<T> {
  T mapRow(Row row);
}
```

**Issue.java**

```
package com.api.pojo;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;

/**
 * It will contain all the fields related to Issue.
 * 
 * @author vishal.zanzrukia
 * 
 */
public class Issue {

  private Cell description;

  /**
   * @return
   */
  public String getDescription() {
    if (description != null) {
      return description.getStringCellValue();
    }
    return null;
  }

  /**
   * @param description
   */
  public void setDescription(Cell description) {
    this.description = description;
  }
}
```

**ExcelColumn.java**

```
package com.api.excel;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import com.api.mapper.SimpleExcelIssueMapper;
import com.api.pojo.Issue;


/**
 * @author vishal.zanzrukia
 * 
 */
public class ExcelColumn {

  private int descriptionColumnIndex;

  /**
   * This is inner class to protect visibility of mapRow method
   * 
   * @author vishal.zanzrukia
   *
   */
  class InnerSimpleExcelIssueMapper implements RowMappable<Issue> {

    @Override
    public Issue mapRow(Row row) {
      Issue issue = new Issue();
      issue.setDescription(row.getCell(descriptionColumnIndex));
      return issue;
    }
  }

  /**
   * set issue description column index<BR>
   * <STRONG>NOTE :</STRONG> index starts from <STRONG>0</STRONG>
   * 
   * @param descriptionColumnIndex
   */
  public void setDescriptionColumnIndex(int descriptionColumnIndex) {
    this.descriptionColumnIndex = descriptionColumnIndex;
  }
}
```

Here, `ExcelColumn` is the class which end user (API user) will use for mapping the excel column index with it's purpose (here, it's description for example).

Now, `ExcelColumn` can `implements` directly to `RowMappable` rather than inner class (`InnerSimpleExcelIssueMapper`), but if I do so, end user (API user) will be able to call `mapRow` method. I don't want to call `mapRow` outside the package because it will create confusion for end user (API user). So I have achieved it using inner class concept.

Is this correct way to do it? Is there any better way to achieve the same?

Is there any `design pattern` applicable here?

Comment: what's the API of ExcelColumn class? Should it return issue by row?

Comment: It is basically the class which will take the input from end user and should give the `Issue`'s object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class say `RowMappableImpl`(in your case `InnerSimpleExcelIssueMapper`) that implements `RowMappable` and implement the method `mapRow()` which returns an `Issue` instance.

From your `ExcelColumn` class, call the `mapRow()` method which is implemented in `RowMappableImpl`. This way the API's client won't be able to call `mapRow()`.

Comment: I have accepted your answer for first approach, but inner static class can't access the outer class instance variables. Please correct the answer so other readers will not get wrong information. Please [refer this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17701360/1326692). So if I want to use the inner class, it is correct way I have done.

Comment: @VishalZanzrukia, I'm sorry, I didn't see the reference to `descriptionColumnIndex` inside the `InnerSimpleExcelIssueMapper ` class. You're right, it can't be a static inner class then. I'll edit my answer, thanks!